# Nut - Bolt - Washer Question

Tags: linear-algebra

A man requires nuts, bolts & washers weighing a total of 1kg. The weight of 1 nut, 1 bolt & 1 washer is 10g, 25g and 5g each respectively. What should be the weight of the nuts, bolts and washers separately so that the quantity of all 3 are equal?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: let $n$ be the number of nuts. Then the total weight of nuts is $10n$, bolts $25n$ and washers $5n$. Adding all of them together you get...

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)